# "A system" is considered singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, singular-subject-and-verb

> Perhaps the highest-profile display of the technology’s potential came
>   in 2016, when a system built by DeepMind, a London-based ai firm owned
>   by Alphabet, Google’s corporate parent, beat one of the world’s best
>   players at Go, an ancient Asian board game.

I am expecting the verb "beat" to be "beats" since "a system" is singular. Can anyone explain why it is "beat"?

Comment: Take a look as the tenses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it's in the past.

"He beats me when he plays me" is present, but "He beat me in 2016 when he played me" is completely correct.